# Fetch values from multiple sheets Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find an Employee ID from the attendance which spans multiple sheets and pull the timestamp into a single sheet.

The Google sheet has multiple sheets in it. There are individual sheets for every working day: [image: Daily sheets]

Each attendance sheet has two columns. In order to know all the times of the employee's login I want to pull in all the occurrences of the employee ID from all the sheets and along with its timestamp to the Consolidation sheet: [image: Consolidation sheet].

I've done a similar thing in Excel and guess can be done in Google sheet using Google Apps script.

It would be helpful if someone can guide me to a built-in or custom function in google sheets.

Comment: I guess you will have to write a custom function for that. If the total amount of data is small enough to fit into the available ram you can just read all the information into javascript objects/arrays and then write it out in the right format to the consolidation sheet.

Comment: @SpiderPig Custom sheet functions cannot utilize any services that require authentication as they are executed as an anonymous user, such as the `SpreadsheetApp` service. See this for more details: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Answer (score 2):

I'll help you with a basic outline, some advice, and some resources to help, but don't expect me to write the whole thing.

---

**Step 1 - Create a custom menu option**

You'll want to be able to access you script from the spreadsheet. You can accomplish this by creating a custom menu option. Here's an [article by google on custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Although google uses the simple trigger `onOpen`, I've found [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to be more reliable.

**Step 2 - Get user input**

It would be nice to be prompted for the id of the employee and have the script work it's magic. Here is an [article by google on dialogs and sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) that discusses how to get user input for a script.

**Step 3 - Read and write data from the spreadsheet**

You can access spreadsheeet data with the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). When calling your script from a custom menu, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet`; however, if you want to test your code in the script editor, there is no "active spreadsheet", so use `SpreadsheetApp.openById` instead.

With access to the spreadsheet, you can call:

```
spreadsheet.getSheetByName("name").getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
spreadsheet.getSheetByName("name").getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).setValues([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
```

Note that `getValues` and `setValues` work with 2-dimensional arrays

*WARNING* - As usual, I/O takes a lot of processing time so avoid superfluously calling `getRange().XetValues`, this [google article about appscript best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) goes into more detail. Also, if you have a LOT of attendance sheets, then you may want to consider condensing them into one.

**Step 4 - Get the appropriate sheets**

You'll need someway to distinguish which sheets in the spreadsheet are attendance sheets:

```
function isAttendanceSheet(sheet) {
  return /Magical regex/.test(sheet.getName);
}

var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets().filter(isAttendanceSheet);
```

Come up with the magical regex that works for you, and this will filter them.

---

Hope this helps and good luck!